# Starting my Flask Application using supervisor

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, supervisord

I have a flask application, which is running perfectly. I have made a .sh file to start the same as below

```
cd /home/ecqsence/QMS_AIMS/ECQ
echo $PATH
if [ ! -d "ecqenv" ]
then
    python3 -m venv ecqenv
fi
source ecqenv/bin/activate
pip install -r ecq/requirements.txt
cd ecq
python main.py
```

When I run the above sh file directly, the Flask application comes up.

Now I am trying to configure the same in supervisor as I need the application to be up when the user is logged. PFB the supervisor conf entry

```
[program:start_ECQ]
command=sh /home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh
user=ecqsence
environment=HOME="/home/ecqsence",USER="ecqsence",PATH="/home/ecqsence/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/Ecq.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/Ecq.out.log
```

But the same is failing with below err.log.

```
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 9: python: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 6: source: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 7: pip: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 9: python: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 6: source: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 7: pip: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 9: python: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 6: source: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 7: pip: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 9: python: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 6: source: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 7: pip: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 9: python: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 6: source: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 7: pip: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 9: python: not found
/home/ecqsence/runEcq.sh: 6: source: not found
```

Request to help me on the same.

Comment: Are you running this on linux machine?

Comment: Yes. I am running on Ubuntu 20.4 LTS.

Comment: Is python installed in that machine? Bcz python is not found and virtual env is not generating. And app is crashing.

Comment: Yes, Python is installed and when I run the .sh file individually, the app is getting started.

Comment: guess you mess up env in some way, compare everything with working shell `printenv`